# sieve of Eratosthenes output error

Tags: c, sieve-of-eratosthenes

i started learning C a couple of days back. I am stuck with this problem on finding the prime numbers using Sieve of Erathosthemes. The code compiles but does not give proper output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define size 100

int main()
{
       int n;
       printf("Enter the value of n\n");
       scanf_s("%d",&n);
       int A[size],i;
       for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
       {
            A[i]=i;
       }
        A[1]=0;
        for(i=0;i<sqrt((float)n);i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n+1;j++)
            {
                if(A[j]%i==0)A[j]=0;
                else A[j]=j;
            }
        }`
        for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
        {
            if(A[i]!=0)printf("%d\n",A[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Your `if(A[j]%i==0)` is obviously wrong, `i` starts with `0`.

Comment: This is not SoE.
Please go through [1] and [2].

[1]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation
[2]http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

- You dont need to initialize every array cell with its number value. You just need to "mark" the cells with 0 or 1.
- In: `for(i=0;i<sqrt((float)n);i++)` you need to iterate up to `n+1`, as you did in other loops.
- As noted in comments: you start with `i=0`, then `if(A[j]%i==0)` is dividing by zero.
- Are you mixing concepts from *Sieve of Erathosthemes* with *Primality by trial division*?.

The following is a possible correction of your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define size 100

int main() {
       int n;
       printf("Enter the value of n\n");
       scanf_s("%d",&n);

       int A[size], i, j;
       
       A[0] = 1;   //zero is not prime, mark it with: 1
       A[1] = 1;   //...same for one

       for(i=2; i < n+1; i++)
            A[i] = 0;

        for(i=2; i < sqrt((float) n+1); i++)       //loop from first prime to sqrt(n+1)
            if (A[i] == 0)                         //if is unmarked, is prime, THEN
                for(j = i*i; j < n+1 ; j = j + i)  //mark prime's multiples 
                    A[j] = 1;

        for(i=0; i < n+1 ;i++)                     //now visit each cell, and print the unmarked ones
            if (A[i] == 0)
                 printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Output for 9:

> 2
>
> 3
>
> 5
>
> 7

Answer (score 0):

A[j]%i is not correct in your program.

I have implemented Sieve of Erathosthemes in below code-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[20];
int i,n,j;
n=20;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    a[i]=i+1;



for(i=2;i<n/2;i++)
{
    for(j=2;j<=(n/i);j++)
    {
        a[(i*j)-1]=0;
    }


}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(a[i]!=0)
    printf(" %d",a[i]);

}

return 0;
}
```